# Task scheduling

Tags: vxworks

My system composed of seven task.
I created some demo RTP in order to examine my system as follows:

```
    int main()
    {
        taskSpawn("/task1" , 107 , VX_NO_STACK_FILL , 2000 , (FUNCPTR)task1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        taskSpawn("/task2" , 106 , VX_NO_STACK_FILL , 2000 , (FUNCPTR)task2, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        taskSpawn("/task3" , 105 , VX_NO_STACK_FILL , 2000 , (FUNCPTR)task3, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        taskSpawn("/task4" , 104 , VX_NO_STACK_FILL , 2000 , (FUNCPTR)task4, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        taskSpawn("/task5" , 105 , VX_NO_STACK_FILL , 2000 , (FUNCPTR)task5, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        taskSpawn("/task6" , 106 , VX_NO_STACK_FILL , 2000 , (FUNCPTR)task6, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        taskSpawn("/task7" , 101 , VX_NO_STACK_FILL , 2000 , (FUNCPTR)task7, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

        taskExit(OK);
    }

void task1() { taskDelay(7); }
void task2() { taskDelay(13); }
void task3() { taskDelay(313); }
void task4() { taskDelay(19); }
void task5() { taskDelay(188); }
void task6() { taskDelay(10); }
void task7() { taskDelay(10); }
```

I ran the RTP and i connected  the Performance profiler.
The performance profiler gave me the CPU usage of each task. 
What i want to check is that each task executes on time,
for example i want to make sure that task1 executes every 7*16 = 112 millisends
(my system clock rate is 60HZ meaning scheduler invoked every 16 milliseconds)

Questions:
1.Is there any way in the profiler to make shure this is happen.
2.If not how can check this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used the profiler, so I don't know anything about it, but I have done what you want before in vxworks. Here is how I did it:

1) Spawn a task with priority = 255 (or lower than any of your real time tasks) which consumes 100% CPU as follows:

---

```
void lowPriTask()
{
    volatile int forever = 1;
    while (forever) {}
}
```

---

2) Install a task switch hook with taskSwitchHookAdd() and your switch hook callback should keep track (in memory) of the old taskId and the new taskId, and the tickGet(), basically just compile a list of this information in memory.

3) Then when you have run your tasks for a while dump the memory to a file and figure out some cool way to examine it/visualize it, maybe with the help of excel or so.

The reason for this lowPri task is because in vxworks the taskSwitchHook is only called when a task switch occurs (obviously) the subtle detail is that if the system is idle then a task switch doesn't occur. So if you are keeping track of the times when a task switches in and out, and the system is idle then you will have some tasks that appear to be hogging a bunch of CPU time, when in fact the system is idle. Like so:

- taskSwitch_In
- taskRuns
- task is done, but no other tasks are ready, so system goes to idle....
- some ticks later a task becomes ready...
- taskSwitch_Out

So if you have a low priority task that consumes 100% of the idle time, then that always forces a task switch immediately after any (higher priority) task is done. So you always see a pattern like this:

- taskSwitch_In
- taskRuns
- taskSwitch_Out (to lowPriTask in the event that no other task is ready)

In addition to this it gives you an accurate estimate of how much idle time there is based on the amount of time that this low priority task runs.

It is crude, but it works.

Comment: Hey,
1.There is a great tool in wind river workbanch called System viewer
which is great for tracing different events timing(like context switch).
2.Can you please explain why you spawn the lowPriTask?

Thanks in advance